# space varying vertical coordinates of model data-- writing netCDF file (xarray)

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray, dimension

Consider using a numerical flow model to simulate a simple 1D advection-diffusion case, in hydraulic engineering, e.g.: evolution of salt concentration (Cs). The domain has no y-dimension, but only X and Z dimension, meaning that the flow is not depth-averaged and, for **1 timestep**, I have the salt concentration:

Cs = Cs(x, z)

where
x: space coordinate (equally spaced vector), and z: vertical coordinate (**non** equally spaced vector).
or more in general, including time, :

Cs = Cs(x, z, t)

Now, x is constant over time and space (meaning that the x-grid is not "moving" slightly back and forth), but z (i.e. the vertical coordinate of each "Layer") is indeed adapting and oscillating up and down.

For each time-step, the model spits out the actual numerical value of the salt concentration, AND the vertical coordinate for each layer (i.e. at each given depth of the fluid). IN Python I could easily "merge" contour the salinity over x and z, by staggering each z on top of its previous level.

Therefore, cords matrix in Python has a number of lines that equals the number of vertical layers and a number of rows that equals the number of x grid points. By so doing, coordinates and Salinity matrices are consistent and may be plotted (contours).

My question now is:
In Python, I want to use x-array to generate/output a netcdf file to read that in with Paraview. I could get started and created a netCDF file, containing (for now) only 1 time-step, ingest that into Paraview and plot it.

However, my problem is that z = z(x), which means that each level height varies along the horzinotal coordinate. So far, I could only apply an equally spaced vertical vector to describe vertical coordinate, and that vector is **not** depending on x, so it is not varying along the horizontal coordinate.

How can I achieve my goal?

```
nx = np.shape(Xp)[1]
nz = Nvert+1




#X vector is linearly spaced, constant dx, and it is OK like that! 
xmin = 0
xmax = 10
X = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nx)

#Z is equally spaced too, by it should NOT be! might vary over vertical AND/or over X!!!
zmin = 0
zmax = 0.5
Z = np.linspace(zmin, zmax, nz)


# merge quantity "qname", at timestep 0, given Nvert vertical layers 
q0       = merge_quant(Nvert, t[0], qname)

#create two matrix coordinates, xk and zk, being consistent is size with q0 
xk, zk   = merge_xnadz(Nvert, t[0])

#assign:
vals = q0

#preallocate data using xarray
ds = xr.Dataset(
{qname: (("z", "x"), vals)},
coords={
    "x": X,
    "z": Z  #---this here should vary but is instead constant..?!?
       }
)

#save to disk
ds.to_netcdf("Testout.nc")
```

How can I add another dimension? **Could I just add the matrix of coordinates in xarray** before saving to netCDF? That would really solve my problem.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Marco

Edit:
Two images, one for model results; and one obtained in PARAVIEW
[image]
[image]

Comment: Long text but good question. A possible work around could be that you first define a DataArray from your output for each time step and then concatenate them into one Dataset.

Comment: @dl.meteo: thanks for the answer. Yes! That is what i have in mind. But before merging all the timesteps, I need to make sure that the general method works (time-step wise), and that is NOT the case now. The problem I am having is WITHIN the first timestep.

Comment: But did you tried to store your data in a `DataArray` and not in a `Dataset`?

Comment: @dl.meteo: 
    ds = xr.Dataset(
    {qname: (("z", "y","x"), vals)},
    coords={
        "x": Xp.squeeze(),
        "y": Y,
        "z": zk[:,0],
    }
)

Can you be more specific? I am very new to xarray and would appreciate some more hints.... Thank you.

Comment: Okay: A `Dataset` is a collection of `DataArray`s http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.html . Wrote your data into a list of DataArrays -> [DataArray(), DataArray(), .] and then use `xarray.concatenate` to get a Dataset.

Comment: @dl.meteo 
as suggested, I've used Datarrays for storing each level. When looping over vertical levels, I append newly calculated to an existing empty holder, stacking it all up. 


d = xr.DataArray(
            q, 
            dims=("level","X"), 
            coords={"X": Xp.squeeze(),
                    "level": zk.squeeze()}        
            )   

Now the problem is: dim(salinity) = dims(x) * dim(lev), for each level (i.e. it must be a _squared_. matrix). I have **130** **levels**. not viable! For each salinity point I want: Sal(x,lev), instead of gridding my data.